# Increment an array copy to count user entered int Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, increment

When I run the program:

```
        Enter a number: 222
        Digit:      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        Occurrences:    1 9
```

*Obviously this is homework. I have scoured over the website for the past four days and have changed the code countless times based on diff ideas, this is my last resort while I continue to try and make changes. Any ideas/ direction to move towards to make this work?

Thanks.

```
import jpb.*;

            public class RepeatDigit {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    //User input
    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a number: ");
    String userInput = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    //Array to store digit counts               
    int[] digitCounts = new int [10];

    while (number > 0) {
        digitCounts[number%10]++;
        number /=10;
    }

    System.out.print("Digit:\t\t");

    //Printing 0-9
    int[] digit = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < digit.length - 1; i1++)
        System.out.print(digit[i1] + " ");
    System.out.print(digit[digit.length - 1]);

    System.out.print("\nOccurrences:    ");

            //Attempt to make a new array copy and compare this with 
            //user input

    int []tempArray= new int [digit.length];
    System.arraycopy(digit, 0, tempArray, 0, digit.length);
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < tempArray.length - 1; i1++)
                if (tempArray[i1] == number);
                    number += 1;


    System.out.print(tempArray[number] + " "); e
    System.out.print(tempArray[tempArray.length -1]);
```

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your program line by line, in order to figure out where its behaviour diverges from what you expect.  Alternatively, you could add lots of print statements to inspect the values of intermediate variables on each loop iteration, etc.

Comment: OK, so nice job telling us this is homework.  Good, that's step one.  However you don't really tell us what expected output is or what it's supposed to do so it's really hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

first off, your

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < digit.length - 1; i1++)
        System.out.print(digit[i1] + " ");
    System.out.print(digit[digit.length - 1]);
```

looks a little unnecessarily hard to read.  you could just do

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < digit.length; i1++)
        System.out.print(digit[i1] + " ");
```

Secondly, I'm guessing that you want to print out the contents of `digitCounts` after the `Occurences` label.  in which case you can just do that in the same way that you printed out the `digit[]` array.

If that's not what you want to do, than please tell me what you actually do want to do, so that I may help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the expected behavior:

```
Enter a number: 222
Digit:      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Occurrences:    3
```

In the code you've shown you convert the entered string into a number, and then try to treat it one character at a time with `%` and `/`. At a glance this loop seems unlikely to work as intended, but luckily there's no need for such an approach. Assuming that this code isn't performance-critical, you can step through the user's input one character at a time and parse that single digit, e.g.:

```
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(c.toString());
    // handle i
}
```

I wouldn't use `arraycopy` for this task unless the homework requires it. Use an array of size 10 filled with 0s. Whenever you parse the digit `x`, increment the value at index `x`.

You seem to have the printing figured out for `digit[]`, you can just do the same with the number of occurences.